# Ubuntu server 17.04, no option of live usb

Tags: grub2, 17.04

I boot from usb. I go to options of that usb.

There are install, rescue and some other options but no option for live usb. I want to login and repair my grub but i cant manage it.

I am stuck on grub screen. I cant login to ubuntu or windows.(i dont want to use windows, i dont care it).

Comment: You don't get the live USB option in Ubuntu server you will have to get the desktop version for that.

Comment: I think that 'rescue' is the option you will need to use ?

Comment: Just use a desktop version live usb and not the server one, like Henry suggested already.

Comment: What about `check disc for defects` on ubuntu server live usb or rescue a broken system?

Comment: I opened shell from usb rescue. BUt despite i made network configuration, it cant get sudo get apt. Failed to fetch itsays :/ if it can connect, i wouuld install bootrepair

Comment: I installed grub. i can see now my OS windows and ubuntu. but it cant login. It stucks at OS screen